# dynamic media and scene-7 integration in AEM

Tags: aem, scene7

Can someone please give insight about Dynamic media and Scene 7 integration in AEM? I would like to understand why we integrate Dynamic Media/Scene-7? Difference between both.

I am not able to find many articles on Scene-7/Dynamic media online.

I would like to understand why we append "/is/image" for .jpg, .png, etc. images and "/is/content" for .gif images in the URL?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is a very broad question. Can you be more specific? DM and S7 are pretty broad product and (not cheap also!). You would only use these products if your business requires the features (technical or otherwise) of these products.

Comment: @i.net : okay :) Actually, recently i am facing issues while rendering images on my website. Images with "is/image" (.jpg, .png, etc) are getting rendered on the website but images with "is/content" (.gif) images do not appear in the website. Even when i try to access image via browser .gif images do not render while other images show up(images appended with "is/image" in the URL)

Comment: In that case you are better off asking specific question with the error details so that we can help.

Comment: @i.net: i believe appending "is/image" to .jpeg, .png, etc. and "is/content" to .gif images in URL is a convention of DM/Scene7. Can you please tell me why we do it?

Comment: Are you getting 404 or 403 when you say the images are not displayed? The is/content and is/image is a convention for relevant content/image.

Comment: @i.net : i am getting 403 error